# How do I attach the Gorillapod to provide the best stabilization in different stituations?

Tags: technique, tripod, gorillapod

Is there a site or document where I can find or learn -- or simply a technique/method -- how to best attach Gorillapod on some element?

It is relatively easy to have a stable pod on ground, even with different non-level plane surface but in lot of situation the "stable" grip isn't like grip on wire/stem or on the top of cabriolt windshield where often only 1 or 2 movment are fixed but one is free, and like Murphy's law says, it will be wrong if it could and weight of the fixed element is acting like an amplifier.

Most of the time I found a temporary balance but some position of the legs give better result than the other and I would avoid to reinventing the wheel each time.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but to me this makes little sense at all. Are you asking how to use the gorillapod legs?

Comment: I think this is a case of "if you cant figure it out, you shouldnt be using one"

Comment: "yes". I can change the leg's form but the question is more "which form to give at legs on specific object to best fix on"

Comment: @DarkCat Studios, I agree, unhopefully it is more the explaination of the problem that is difficult. For example, what is the best way to grip on the corner of an open door (and also what to avoid) like the 3 legs on the vertical edge due to weight where 3 legs on the horizontal edge is maybe  worst than 2 and 1 catching the vertical ...

Comment: This site works best when you have a specific question; asking about all of the possibilities generally doesn't work. If you have a _specific_ situation you can't figure out, you could ask about that.

Comment: This is why the question start with "Is there a site or document where I can find or learn ..." and not "give all the trick ant this ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera + tripod has a centre of mass. The setup is the most stable if the stabilizing points are the farther apart from this centre of mass. Stabilizing point = that point which is being fixed in space. This can be the end of legs standing on the floor, but also it can be something you tie the leg around, etc.

So in general: put the legs apart, fix them in space.

Prefer putting it on ground or flat surface, than gripping an object. And avoid those scenarios when the legs are in a kind of line, like in the GorillaPod Magnetic ad.

If you are truly helpless, use a tripod! :-) And if you are a rich guy, buy a SteadyCam :-).

Comment: thanks for the method. So it is often better to the longer and apart from each other the better it should be in general

Comment: Yes, that's right.